# Wordpress CMS после как статичный сайт

Tags: wordpress, cms

У меня есть сайт с Wordpress CMS  хотел сайт без этого использовать как статичный. С помощью программы я скачал файлы сайта и после чего посмотрел только стили работали а карусель/javascript/jquery ничего не работало. Вопрос такой: как удалить Wordpress из сайта и использовать как статичный?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Удалить" WordPress из сайта - занятие проблематичное. Посты и страницы WordPress генерируются динамически, при этом контент выбирается из базы mySQL.

Если очень хочется потерять возможности и функционал CMS, то ок - надо пройтись парсером по всем страницам сайта и записать полученный html. А потом этот html выложить на сервер вместо файлов WordPress.

Comment: Говорите,сложно и долго будет да?

Comment: Если не делали раньше - непросто. Лучше нанять фрилансера, у них часто бывают свои парсеры.

Comment: Понятно блогадарю а можно вам еще маленький вопрос задать?

Comment: можно, но лучше не мне, а создайте новый вопрос

Comment: Понял блогадарю

Answer (score -1):

Путей несколько. Если провайдер даёт тебе хостинг на Wordpress и не даёт возможность его удалить, то просто измени файл index.php дабы подгружались твои ресурсы вместо Wordpres'a. Если же твой хостинг позволяет, просто удали все файлы из public_html либо www (опять же зависит от провайдера)

Comment: Спасибо но,знаете это сайт моего друга и я хочу получить файлы(Стили страницы т.д) И потом удалить все Wordpress.А можете по конкретнее обяьснить?

Comment: Господи, ну откуда вы вот такие знатоки? " просто измени файл index.php дабы подгружались твои ресурсы вместо Wordpres'a" - это клинический бред просто. Нулевое понимание того, как работает WP. "просто удали все файлы из public_html" - ну и грохнется весь сайт - дальше-то что?

Comment: Ну изивини, "про".

Answer (score -1):

Страницы можно взять из админки wordpress->страницы. Копировать именно код страницы в редакторе (там все просто). Если нет доступа к админке - копаться в mysql.

Соответственно, стили - внешний вид -> редактор -> все файлы css

Картинки из папки wp-content/uploads. И из темы wp-content/themes.

Может где-то что-то напутал с путями, но как-то так.

И, да, база mysql то есть?

Comment: "Копировать код страницы в редакторе"  - не работает на 100%. html страницы получается в результате работы php-шаблона страницы с использованием контента, который можно найти в админке в редакторе страниц.

Comment: "И, да, база mysql то есть?" - ну это финал апофеоза. Сайт на WP не бывает без базы.

Comment: Имелось ввиду, была ли она скопирована. Удалить wordpress из сайта на wordpress - вот это - финал апофеоза! Проще заново написать.